# after run a code a range value changes and get a error REF

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with various sheets named Alert* (each Alert sheet name have a different date on it) and client sheet. The time that I run code to Copy and Paste the information in 2 sheets named client I am facing an issue.

The Copying and Paste are working fine. However, it deletes the information in Range ("K16", "C1" & "C2") in all my sheets named **Alert***. It is not a big problem, because I still can copy this information once again from the client sheet.

I am trying many ways to copy and paste code, and I can't make it work.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim sw As Worksheet: Set sw = Sheets("Client*")

 For Each sht In Worksheets
    If sht.Name Like "Alert*" Then
        sht.Range("K16").Value = sw.range("J3")
        sht.Range("C1").Value = sw.range("C1")
        sht.Range("C2").Value = sw.range("C2")
    End If
Next ws
```

I try 
Dim sht As Worksheet
set sht = worksheets("Alert*)

ActiveSheet.Range("J3").Copy sht.Range("K16")
  ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C2").Copy sht.Range("C1:C2")

But it is not working.

Maybe it would be possible to use a loop to check all the sheets named Alert* and paste the information from Client sheet to the correct range.

Comment: Have you tried `ws.Range("K16").Formula = "='Client Review'!J3"`?

Comment: I did and for some reason  it did not worked.

Comment: Have you stepped through the error checker for the formula on the worksheet which *generally* helps work out where the error is caused from?

Comment: Yes, I did, and I could not find it.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see anywhere in your code where the sheet `"Client Review"` is deleted or manipulated - have I missed something? Also does [this MS document about the REF error](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-correct-a-ref-error-822c8e46-e610-4d02-bf29-ec4b8c5ff4be) help?

Comment: @SamuelEverson here `ClientReview.Name = "Client Review " & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yyyy")
ws.Delete` the Client review was deleted
`ClientReview.Move before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)` here the new client review will be moved to teh correct position

Comment: Per my link to MS document about the REF error: *"This happens most often when cells that were referenced by formulas get deleted, or pasted over."*

Comment: In your code, what is the `ClientReview` object - is this a worksheet you have renamed the `(name)` property to?

Comment: @SamuelEverson ClienReview is a sheet name. 
here `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    If ws.Name Like "Client Review*" And ws.Name <> "Client Review" Then` for each worksheet named Client Review* and Client Review. 
This code is to copy and paste all the information from a client review* to a Client Review

Comment: The statement doesn't work as you expect it to - your `For Each` statement is looping through all your worksheets and finding a sheet that's name is `Like "Client Review*"` and is *`less than`* or *`greater than`* `"Client Review"`. If **both** criteria are met, then it will `Exit For` and `ws` then represents the sheet that satisfied **both** criteria. For it to work the way you are anticipating change the `And` to an `Or` then the `Exit For` can execute if **either** condition is met, not **both**.

Comment: @SamuelEverson I will try what you are saying

Comment: @SamuelEverson the copying and paste from 1 client review sheet to another client review sheet is working fine, the code copies everything that need to be copied and paste in the correctly place. The problem is after running this code for some reason all range ("K16") in all sheets named Alert*  loses value and show REF error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are to assume that you create a new worksheet named "Client Review" manually or by some other method not shown, I believe the below will help you achieve your desired outcome.

It will essentially look for a worksheet called `"Client Review*"` (let's called this Worksheet A), then copy the ranges from that worksheet to the `"Client Review"` (Worksheet B), and then it will delete A and rename B to have a date stamp on it, so when you re-run this another day when you have recreated the `"Client Review"` worksheet (i.e Worksheet A).

If all I said above makes sense, then you would have to ensure you update the formula for K16 once you have recreated the `Client Review` Worksheet.

I've added another loop similar to yours to ensure every worksheet named `Client*` does have the formula (`"='" & ws.Name & "'!J3"`)

```
Sub CopyOldToNew()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.DisplayAlerts = False: Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False 'For less lag
Dim wsClientReview As Worksheet: Set wsClientReview = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Client Review")
Dim wsPreviousClientReview As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error GoTo ErrorTrue

today = Format(Date, "MM.DD.YYYY")
For Each wsPreviousClientReview In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wsPreviousClientReview.Name Like "Client Review*" And wsPreviousClientReview.Name <> "Client Review" Then
        'wsPreviousClientReview.Activate
        Exit For
    End If
Next ws

wsPreviousClientReview.Range("A22:N250").Copy

wsClientReview.Range("A22:N250").Paste
wsClientReview.Range("J3").Value = wsPreviousClientReview.Range("J3").Value
wsClientReview.Range("G8:H12").Value = wsPreviousClientReview.Range("G8:H12").Value
wsClientReview.Name = "Client Review " & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yyyy")
ws.Delete

wsClientReview.Move before:=Thisworbkook.Sheets(1)

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "Client*" Then
        ws.Range("K16").Value = wsClientReview.Range("J3").Value
    End If
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.DisplayAlerts = True: Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
Exit Sub

ErrorTrue:
MsgBox "No manually added sheets identified."
Alert.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.DisplayAlerts = True: Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, But this formula `"='" & ws.Name & "'!J3"` is on Sheets Named Alert*. I need the range K19 in each sheet named Alert* to have the same value of the the string on range J3 in the client review.

Comment: how youcan see here `For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name Like "Client*" Then
Alert.Range("K16").Value = "='" & ws.Name & "'!J3"
End If

Next ws` I already did what you are saying, but with this loop only 1 sheet named Alert will have the value on K16; and I need all the sheets named Alert and Alert*

Comment: @Fah when you say you need all the Sheets named Alert* to have the value from Client Review J3, do you mean the Code Name or the actual name on the tabs? The code above in your comment loops through all the worksheets and checks their Tab name for the string "Client*", but then you use `Alert.Range` which suggests you are using the code name of a single worksheet, and that's why your loop only updates that worksheet... I also updated my For Loop, I'm unsure but might be what you are after,...